# writing a makefile template to handle multiple c++ extensions

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to work out how to write a makefile template that handles multiple c++ extensions, for a given list of source files - but don't want to have separate rules for each possible extension.  Is this possible?

e.g.

```
TMP_CPPEXTS := cpp c++
TMP_OBJDIR := ~/objfiles
TMP_SOURCEFILES := foo.cpp bar.c++
TMP_BASENAMES := $(basename $(TMP_SOURCEFILES))
TMP_OBJFILES := $(addprefix $(TMP_OBJDIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(notdir $(TMP_BASENAMES))))
TMP_DEPFILES :=$(addprefix $(TMP_OBJDIR)/,$(addsuffix .d,$(notdir $(TMP_BASENAMES))))

BD_EXTFROMBASE = $(strip $(foreach TMP_EXT,$(2),$(foreach TMP_NAME,$(1),$(if $(filter $(addsuffix .$(TMP_EXT),$(TMP_NAME)),$(TMP_SOURCEFILES)),$(EXT)))))

$(TMP_OBJFILES) : $(TMP_OBJDIR)/%.o : %.$(call BD_EXTFROMBASE,$*,$(TMP_CPPEXTS))
    g++ -c $< -o $@

$(TMP_DEPFILES) : $(TMP_OBJDIR)/%.d : %.$(call BD_EXTFROMBASE,$*,$(TMP_CPPEXTS))
    g++ -m $< -o $@
```

I have verified that TMP_OBJFILES contains the expected object files, but cant seem to get the rule itself to work? Any suggestions other than use separate rules/macros?

Comment: Having a separate rule for each extension really isn't all that bad, certainly not compared to what you're attempting. Is there some reason other than curiosity?

Comment: it is for an existing build system - so yes it is that bad having duplicates of every build macro just for a different c++ extension, as well as needing separate lists of "c++" file base names.  The template only takes a list of c++ file basenames as input, my example above is only to show what (roughly) I am trying to achieve.

I am aware that it is possible since ive seen a similar example that works, however I cannot seem to adapt it to our case.

see: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/124637/makefile-for-c-one-file-programs#post608682

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
define templ
$(TMP_OBJDIR)/%.o: %.$(1)
    g++ -c $$< -o $$@
endef

$(foreach ext,$(TMP_CPPEXTS),$(eval $(call templ,$(ext))))
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't quite work as planned - and generated a lot of undesirable output. Is there no way to easily create a rule matching the source filename from an array of specified objects files given the pattern $(OBJDIR)/%.o ?

Comment: using something to do -:<br/>
<br/>
OBJDIR = /foo/bar<br/>
OBJFILES = $(OBJDIR)/first.o $(OBJDIR)/second.o<br/>
SRCFILES = ~/src/third/first.cpp ~/src/fourth/second.cxx<br/>
<br/>
$(OBJFILES) : $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(get the sourfile from $(SRCFILES))<br/>
    ....<br/>
<br/>
??